# How can I autoclick on a loading page?

Tags: javascript

Hi there I would like to autofill a page on loading which is include ng-repeat parameter. well I need a script to doing this and automatically click on one of the option appear. the following code is the html code of the page.

I wrote this script but did not work. document.querySelectorAll('.sd-Items')[1].click();

```
<div class="sd-titleSideBar">
    <strong>Color Selection</strong>
</div>
<div class="sd-selectColor">
    <!-- ngRepeat: color in model.colors -->
    <div ng-repeat="color in model.colors" class="inventory sd-Items ng-scope 
  selectedItem" ng-class=" 
 {'selectedItem': color.id == selectedColor}" ng-click="colorClick(color.id)">
        <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border-width: 2px; border-style: 
 ridge !important; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="col-md-1" ng-style="{'background-color': color.omi}"></div>
        <label class="ng-binding"> White</label>
        <!-- ngIf: !color.ohc -->
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: color in model.colors -->
    <div ng-repeat="color in 
 model.colors" class="inventory sd-Items ng-scope" ng-class=" 
{'selectedItem': color.id == selectedColor}" ng-click="colorClick(color.id)">
        <div style="width: 30px; height: 30px; border-width: 2px; border-style: 
ridge !important; background-color: rgb(25, 25, 175);" class="col-md-1" ng-style="{'background-color': color.omi}"></div>
        <label class="ng-binding"> Blue</label>
        <!-- ngIf: !color.ohc -->
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: color in model.colors -->
</div>
```

Comment: So what did you try that did not work?

Comment: document.querySelectorAll('.sd-Items')[8].click();

Comment: And what happens when you try that?

Comment: Indeed I would like add this script to Autofill extension that click on one of this object.

Comment: Is this Javascript or are you using angularjs?

Comment: @Amy nothing, I'm dong right??

Comment: @PiyushP I am not very professional I think the webpage wrote in angularjs. But I would like to use a JS.

Comment: Triggering a click on an element probably isn't the right approach. In the AngularJS controller you probably want to redirect with `window.location.href=` instead. You'd need to show the actual script code.

Comment: @MSSHD Well with the code you've added to the question, I would expect the text "document.querySelectorAll('.sd-Items')[8].click();" to literally appear *on the page*.  "nothing happens" tells us nothing useful.  Do you have your browsers devtools open to observe any errors?

Comment: @Amy I when I run "document.querySelectorAll('.sd-Items')[1].click();" in console then I will get "undefined" message.

Comment: Can you share complete code? or can you try with (.sd-Items)[0] instead of 8?

Comment: @PiyushP The same result with [0] and [1]. actually the [8] is not true as the are only two.

Comment: I think you need to handle these events using AngularJS. You're calling click() function, but executing colorClick().

Comment: Change `ng-click="colorClick(color.id)"` with `onclick="alert('hi');"` and see what you get for that element

Comment: @PiyushP I change as you did and rum my script after that a the alert appear on page.

Comment: @MSSHD, ok in that case you need to find the corresponding controller and define your function there. Do you have controller for this?

Comment: You cant call  querySelectorAll and then call angular directive method. Try to call it from controller of this page like 'this.colorClick(this.model.colors[0].id)' or something like that (I'm not working with angularjs many years - it's outdated)

Comment: @GeorgeMA when I run "colorClick(color[0].id)" I will get this message "Uncaught ReferenceError: colorClick is not defined"

Comment: @PiyushP where I can find the controller?

Comment: It's because you calling it from nowhere call it from controller itself using 'this'. I don't know which structure of your code but try to read this https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_controllers.asp

Comment: And use it from some lifecycle hook like 'onInit'

Comment: @GeorgeMA I run the code  "this.colorClick(this.model.colors[0].id)" and get this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'colors' of undefined"

Comment: I don't know which code and where you run. Update your answer with examples

Comment: @GeorgeMA What does mean [0] before ".id" ?

Comment: Are you serious? Hope this is you own project :)

Comment: '[0]' means that you point on first element of array

Comment: @GeorgeMA sorry for stupid question!

Comment: @MSSHD, please read through Javascript tutorial first and then try AngularJS tutorial before you experiment with your code. It will help you find answers and will help your Javascript skills.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/200418/discussion-on-question-by-msshd-how-can-i-autoclick-on-a-loading-page).

Answer (score 1):

If you're calling methods of AngularJs, then you need to define those methods inside controller for that element.

You can get more information from this webpage and this tutorial for angularjs.

https://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_databinding.asp

See AngularJS controller section.